# Laravel- 5.5 App\Comment::user must return a relationship instance.

Tags: php, laravel, one-to-many, laravel-5.5

I want to display products comments. But When I do that, it gives me above error. How can I fix that ?

I'm using One To Many relationship beetwen `product-comments` and `user-comments`

Product model;

```
 public function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment','product_id','id');
    }
```

User Model;

```
public function comments() {

         return $this->hasMany('App\Comment','user_id','id');
     }
```

Comment Model;

```
public function user(){

        $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function product(){
        $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }
```

Blade file

```
<figcaption class="text-center">{{$comment->user->username}}</figcaption>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to return relationship. So add `return` to the `user()` relationship definition method:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

The same is with the `product()` relationship:

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
}
```